# How to add a progress bar to a python plugin?

Tags: qgis, python

I would like to add some type of progress bar to my Qgis python plugin.  Can someone point me to an example?

Comment: As this is really a Python & Qt question, you'd probably get better answers on stackoverflow

Comment: You might want to have a look at [QProgressBar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qprogressbar.html) before heading over to stackoverflow and asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a simple use case of progress bar in PyQt, use can use it in your Qgis plugin 
http://acaciaecho.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/pyqtprogressbar/